# Restarting Mysql Database in Cpanel on a shared Server

Tags: mysql, cpanel

How can I restart Mysql Database in Cpanel on a shared server? I read through this link https://www.psychz.net/client/question/en/how-to-restart-apache-server-in-cpanel.html but I havent succeeded.

Comment: Thats probably because that information is about restarting Apache :)

Answer (score 3):

if you have access to cPanel account (port 2083 after your domain like https://example.com:2083) and not WHM interface (port 2087 that is used for root and resellers account) , you can't restart MySql.